# Running the Linux Kernel Module ( Hello World )

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

I am trying to run a hello world kernel module but its showing module.h is no present. but i have module.h in /usr/src/linux.2.xx.xx/includes/.Please help me how to set this path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following in your shell in the directory with the source of your module:

```
export KDIR=/usr/src/linux.2.xx.xx
make -C $KDIR M=`pwd`
```

That header should be used via `#include <linux/module.h>`

Answer (score 0):

try to touch a new makefile which coding like below

```
ifneq ($(KERNELRELEASE),)
obj-m := hello.o
else
KERNELDIR ?= /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
PWD := $(shell pwd)
default:
        $(MAKE) -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(PWD) modules
endif
```

1. this makefile should name "Makefile"
2. put it in the same directory with the hello.c file